# Certification courses

Tags: certification

I would like to organise some courses in Magento for my team. i'm searching about free online courses or ressources and test sample

In advance thank you

Answer (score 2):

For certification You can refer the study guide of the certification exam and can study for the exam from official Magento site  [Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/)

Find points from study guide and refer the site.Also be practical with all the Magento 2 concepts.
You can refer to [Swiftotter](https://swiftotter.com/) for practice tests ,but they are paid.

Thank You.